# Unexpected response from Converting from curl to python request.post

Tags: curl, python-requests, http-post, python-3.8

I am trying to implement a working curl call into Python3.8.

```
curl -H application/x-www-form-urlencoded --silent -d "client_id=bob&client_secret=djfheucnjdi54ndjdjddkdjs&grant_type=password&scope=openid email profile&username=user1&password=password" -X POST https://some.okta.com/auth/api/v1/token
```

The above curl call (sensitive data modified) is successful and returns a json:

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "access_token": "**********************************************************************",
    "scope": "openid profile email",
    "id_token": "**********************************************************************"
}
```

I have tried to convert this to Python, then verified with online curl to python converted, but dont get the expected result.

The python code:

```
import requests

okta_headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
}

okta_parameters = 'client_id=bob&client_secret=djfheucnjdi54ndjdjddkdjs&grant_type=password&scope=openid email profile&username=user1&password=password'

response = requests.post('https://some.okta.com/auth/api/v1/token', headers=okta_headers, data=okta_parameters)
print(response.content)
```

but getting the following output, which looks like the source code of the page(?):

```
b'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<!--[if IE 7]><html lang="en" class="lt-ie10 lt-ie9 lt-ie8"><![endif]-->\n<!--[if IE 8]><html lang="en" class="lt-ie10 lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->\n<!--...
```

Any idea why and/or how do I get that json from the original curl call?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATE

> hm.... I copied the output directy from
> formatter.xyz/curl-to-python-converter just to make sure I wasnt doing
> anything silly.

So you can't view the request headers?  If not can you change the url, to your own server to get a look at the headers?  You really need to view the headers. 
Curl usually has a configuration or context that has the default headers. It is possible the two revs have different default. The faults are used except for the values you overwrite in the curl option.  
Whenever I make a curl request I provide most of the request parameters.
These is my standard request header (PHP).

```
$request = array();
$request[] = "Host: www.example.com";
$request[] = "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
$request[] = "User-Agent: MOT-V9mm/00.62 UP.Browser/6.2.3.4.c.1.123 (GUI) MMP/2.0";
$request[] = "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5";
$request[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
$request[] = "Cache-Control: no-cache";
$request[] = "Pragma: no-cache";
```

**END OF UPDATE**

---

---

There must be two different request headers between the two.  
If you make the smallest error/typo in the request, it can have a significant effect on the response.  
If your curl gives you a method/option to capture the out going request header, compare the two. 
If not you need to carefully check every detail of the request header and find the typo.
Also make sure there is no 304 redirect.  A redirect can change things between two different curl functions.

Comment: hm.... I copied the output directy from https://formatter.xyz/curl-to-python-converter just to make sure I wasnt doing anything silly.

Comment: So @Misuderstood you were at least partially correct, there was a typo which I hadnt noticed. Im getting a 404 now. Im going to give it some effort since this is a new issue now. Thank you for the quick response.